# i.id. random variables problem

Tags: random-variable, density-function, iid

Given $N$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3, \ldots$, each with uniform distribution in $[0, 1]$.
How can I find the probability that one of the them is maximum, say, what is $p := P(X_1 \text{ is the largest})$?

I think all have equal probabilities of being the largest, so $p = 1/N$, am I correct?

I understand that when it comes to maximum of these RVs, the cdf is the product of each random variable, but I am not able to apply that to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the event that $X_1$ is the largest by $A$, intuitively (by symmetry), your guess is correct.

Formally, we can prove this as follows:
\begin{align}
& P(A) = P[X_1 \geq X_2, X_1 \geq X_3, \ldots, X_1 \geq X_N] \\
= & \int_0^1 P[X_2 \leq x, X_3 \leq x, \ldots, X_N \leq x]f_{X_1}(x) dx \\
= & \int_0^1 P[X_2 \leq x]P[X_3 \leq x] \cdots P[X_N \leq x]f_{X_1}(x) dx \\
= & \int_0^1 x^{N - 1} dx \\
= &\frac{1}{N}.
\end{align}